# Is there a way to hide intermediate arrowheads in PlantUML activity diagrams?

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

I'm trying to remove the intermediate arrowhead in the activity diagram circled in red below:

[image]

```
@startuml
start

repeat
  :read data;
  :generate diagrams;
repeat while (more data?) is (yes)
->no;
stop
@enduml
```

Source: [PlantUML docs - Activity Diagram (new) - repeat](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#219cebcef334f265)

I've tried adding `-[hidden]->` after `(yes)`, but that hides the entire arrow which is not what I'm looking for.

Instead, I need the circled arrowhead above to be hidden.

Comment: You know that neither the arrow heads nor the hexagonal decision node are UML compliant? (IIRC there is an option to set compliant output)

Comment: I suspect that arrow comes from a dummy node in graphviz, used to get nicely back to the start.